# How to setup an auto email for a specific group sign up?

Tags: forms

I am looking for instructions on how to set up an auto email when someone signs up and joins a specific group.  Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Peter, you can find the CiviRules extension here: https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules (or in the extensions list when you do **Administer>Extension** and then click on the **Add New** tab)

Documentation on how CiviRules work can be found here : https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

If there is an Activity connected to the 'join a group' then you could use Scheduled Reminders.

Assuming there isn't then I think CiviRules extension may be the only non-code route.

For Drupal systems, you could use Webforms for the 'sign up' form and then use Webform to trigger the email.